# Power dissipation formula

Tags: voltage, power, current, dc-dc-converter, buck

Is the below formula, present on page 26 of this [buck converter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) correct to use?

[image]

Or should I use the formula mentioned in the 3 paragraph of this [accepted answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/calculating-power-loss-in-switching-power-regulator)?

Comment: The question is incomplete. You do not actually say what you are wanting. If it is the power dissipation in a buck regulator given power in and power out (So dissipation = Pin-Pout) then Olin's answer is correct. [Olins answers are correct 99.9876% of the time].  || The formula above has the units of power but is not obviously meaningful. || Iload x Vsat is the dissipation in the output switch when on. || Iq is undefined - if it is I quiescent then its the standby power. This may or may not be relevant when loaded. || Giving a source reference would help.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, thank you for the comment. So, the formula in the TI datasheet is incorrect for calculating the power dissipation of the buck converter?

Comment: I've now seen where the formula came from in the datasheet / app note and what it means in context. ||  Both answers SHOULD give approximately the same answer. || Olin's is easier by measurement. Measure Power in. Measure power out.  Difference is dissipation . || TI formulat assumes most dissipation is due to losses in switch in IC. They assume that Iin = Iload x Vout/Vin. OK if transformer is lossless and switching losses small. THEN Dissipation in switch = Iin x V_switch_saturated. Substitute Iin as above and you get their expression.

Answer (score 1):

The power dissipation in a buck regulator (or any regulator) given Pin (power in) and Pout (power out) is
Dissipation = Pin-Pout
So Olin's answer is correct.
[Olins answers are correct 99.9876% of the time].

The TI formula is also "correct enough" but is more theoretical.
Both answers SHOULD give approximately the same answer.
Olin's is easier by measurement.
Measure Power in.
Measure power out.
Difference is dissipation.

TI formulat assumes most dissipation is due to losses in switch in IC.
They assume that Iin = Iload x Vout/Vin. OK if transformer is lossless and switching losses small.
THEN Dissipation in switch = Iin x V_switch_saturated.
Substitute Iin as above and you get their expression.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much for the answer. In my case, Input Voltage is 24V. Input current is 1A. Output Voltage is 5V. Output current is 3A. So, Input Power - Output power = 24W - 15W = 8W. This is a very high power dissipation right, even for a buck converter? Any suggestions to avoid this high power dissipation?

Comment: @Freshman  Fi 6.9, page 9 in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) indicates an efficiency of about 75-80% for those figures. Your 8w losses for 24w in is 67% efficient - somewhat lower than their figures. || Fig 6.8 suggests switch losses (Vsat x Iload x Vo.Vin) is substantially less than 6w or 8w. || Possible improvements may be found in inductor losses (wire thickness, core material, ...), cooling, Schottky diode losses, ... .

Comment: [1N5822](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/d8/3f/72/85/bc/90/4e/f7/CD00001626.pdf/files/CD00001626.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00001626.pdf) - fig 10.2 page 4  is very marginal here. It's a 3A diode and your Iout is 4 or 5A. It's Vf is around 0.6V - OK in many uses but maybve several watts dissipation.

Comment: Exmple only - [This diode](https://www.panjit.com.tw/upload/datasheet/SVM1045V2B.pdf) is about as good as you reasonably get. Cost is $1.27 in 1 quantity. Still not perfect. || What inductor are you using?